# JFileChooser selected direcory

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have next code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnNajitPDFCache) {
        JFileChooser chooser;
           String choosertitle = "Select directory.";
        chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setApproveButtonText("OK");
        //
        // disable the "All files" option.
        //
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        //    
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(parent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            textFieldPDFCache.setText(chooser.getCurrentDirectory()+"");
        }
    }
}
```

That's Ok. I choose c:\test folder in opened chooser form and next I click on button OK.

But `chooser.getCurrentDirectory()` return only c:\ . Why? What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`getCurrentDirectory()` returns the current directory that is opened in the 
`JFileChooser`. When you are selecting `C:\test` you opened `C:\` directory, so you are getting `C:\` on `getCurrentDirectory()`

The `getSelectedFile()` returns the file that is selected (in your case the file is a directory). So you if you want the directory that is selected by the user use `getSelectedFile()`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `chooser.getSelectedFile()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Set Canonical path as
 File Canonicalpath = new File(new File("C:/").getCanonicalPath());